# Magento catalog search page problem

Tags: magento-1.9

I am facing some strange behaviour in catalogsearch/result page

in this website I have a product called "del rio"

This is my url search: https://www.wed2b.co.uk/catalogsearch/result/?q=Del+rio

strange it does not show the product not even on first page it's around 4 or 5 when actually it should show in page 1 and first product.
does anyone have any idea why and if there is a fix?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the search engine you are using and the parameters you have set. I think everyone uses a custom one, as Magento's default search engine isn't great, to say the least.

If you were to use Solr for example, you can give weight to specific attributes, so matches on names or skus would be more important than matches on other fields.

The excellent [Solr Brige extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/solr-bridge-search.html) is a bit dear, but it's really worth the expense. Remember a good search is a very important key feature on a store.

Comment: Thank's for your reply. I will take plug in extension into consideration.